# Vue typescript component extend style

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am learning Vuejs with typescript components. Using class based components was really straight forward for me but the other type using Vue.extend({}) gives me errors. Can anyone point me in the direction of articles, blog posts or videos that I can learn more about migrating a vue component based on the Vue.extend style on class based components.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope below links will help you to figure it out

https://ordina-jworks.github.io/frontend/2019/03/04/vue-with-typescript.html
[https://www.sitepoint.com/class-based-vue-js-typescript](https://www.sitepoint.com/class-based-vue-js-typescript/)

Comment: this has put me on the right track...and has me productive. thank you

Comment: glad to hear that it helps you :)